# Look up next date a class is taught after current date, referencing another sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, importrange

I'm trying to create a spreadsheet that lists a series of unique class names, and then checks a schedule spreadsheet for the NEXT time that class is taught.

[Here is a sample sheet I'm looking to make](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HWi8rLSmnJPOyc8ThlFGFM4GhI55CfbCHvE2-s-QN50/edit#gid=0), with the highlighted cells being the ones that need formulas. And [here is a second sheet with the data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/157E80WQaamKMRi6V4cnFWMMFMTEhdlfwALiqmsr0-JY/edit?usp=sharing). So the formula should:

1. Use the "Tab" column of the first spreadsheet to point towards the
   appropriate tab of the destination sheet.
2. Some kind of Index-Match for the class name?
3. (and this is the hard one) Take today's date into account to find the next time a given session is taught.

Column D (for the NEXT next time the session is taught) should be just the same fomula as column C, but with the date in column C substituted for today's date.

The result should be a spreadsheet that lists each class and the next two times that class will be held.

Here's my best attempt at this, with B2 being the class name I'm trying to match, column A of the schedule sheet being my dates, and column B of the schedule sheet being my class names. I didn't attempt to make the "Tab 1" part driven by the formula:

`=iferror(index((IMPORTRANGE("157E80WQaamKMRi6V4cnFWMMFMTEhdlfwALiqmsr0-JY","'Tab 1'!A1:A80")),(match(ArrayFormula($B2&today()),ArrayFormula(IMPORTRANGE("157E80WQaamKMRi6V4cnFWMMFMTEhdlfwALiqmsr0-JY","'Tab 1'!B1:B80")&(IMPORTRANGE("157E80WQaamKMRi6V4cnFWMMFMTEhdlfwALiqmsr0-JY","'Tab 1'!A1:A80"))),-1)),""))`

That -1 at the end is supposed to return the smallest result that is greater than my class name concatenated with the current date. But while it works for some cells, it definitely doesn't work for others. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Add some sample data and the expected result for each case.

Comment: Updated with sample data.

Comment: Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts and attempts to write the formulas you are looking for.

Comment: Updated with my janky formula.

Answer (score 0):

In C2 and dragged down to suit:

```
=array_constrain(query({importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/157E80WQaamKMRi6V4cnFWMMFMTEhdlfwALiqmsr0-JY/edit#gid=0","'Tab 1'!A1:B10");importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/157E80WQaamKMRi6V4cnFWMMFMTEhdlfwALiqmsr0-JY/edit#gid=28833949","'Tab 2'!A2:B10");IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/157E80WQaamKMRi6V4cnFWMMFMTEhdlfwALiqmsr0-JY/edit#gid=416018764","'Tab 3'!A2:B10")},"select Col1 where Col2 ='"&B2&"'limit 2 offset 1 ",0),1,1)
```

should return the dates you show as required (provided access is granted for the imports) for `Next Taught`, but the other column is a different question and you have not explained how 'today' fits in with a post dated December 3 where the results for 'Next Taught` precede that.

You might prefer to separate the above into what may be easier to understand and adapt:

Say in G1:

```
={  
importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/157E80WQaamKMRi6V4cnFWMMFMTEhdlfwALiqmsr0-JY/edit#gid=0","'Tab 1'!A1:B10");  
importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/157E80WQaamKMRi6V4cnFWMMFMTEhdlfwALiqmsr0-JY/edit#gid=28833949","'Tab 2'!A2:B10");  
importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/157E80WQaamKMRi6V4cnFWMMFMTEhdlfwALiqmsr0-JY/edit#gid=416018764","'Tab 3'!A2:B10")  
}
```

then instead in C2 and copied down to suit:

```
=array_constrain(query(G:H,"select G where H ='"&B2&"'limit 2 offset 1 ",0),1,1)
```